# AVD task shows in task-bar but cannot open its window in desktop view

Tags: android

Whenever I start any android virtual device, its starts and is shown in the task bar at bottom. However, on clicking this on task bar the device window just doesn't pop up. I'm unable to test my apps because of this problem.

Tried to recreate new virtual devices but same problem. Please help I cannot test my apps because of this. using windows 8 64-bit, eclipse IDE. Thanks

Comment: how much RAM have you allotted?

Comment: Try reducing your AVD's RAM to 512 or 256 and heap to 32. Choose a smaller device. Then if you need big screens you can scale your AVD's size. Go to Run Configurations -> Target (tab) -> now add this line "-scale 0.75" without quotes in the Additional Emulator Command Line Options

Comment: it has nothing to do with avd's configurations, it used to work properly before. ram is 200mb. the avd boots properly i can see that in aero peek but when i want to bring up this window it doesnt start the window on my screen. weird, it is driving me nuts but i'm just going to uninstall everything and install it again. thanks for the help appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Found one possible answer that worked for me.

I changed my screen resolution from 4k to 1080, because the AVD was just 1080.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot understand the real issue here, but here goes my suggestions.

1. Create AVDs with much lower RAM (512 or 266)
2. Let heap be (32 or 16)
3. If you have bigger screens you can scale your AVD's size. Go to Run Configurations -> Target (tab) -> now add this line `-scale 0.75` without quotes in the Additional Emulator Command Line Options, this will scale the display of your AVD.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the settings > display and change multiple displays option to "duplicate"